# Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I am trying to build my project but facing the following error:

```
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I have checked my
windows-->Prefrences--> Installed JRE path, that points to open jdk only as below:

[image]

can someone help me to resolve the issue?
Path pointing to my JDK is below :
[image]

Comment: It's right in the error message. That looks like the path of a jvm, not of a jkd. Is this ubuntu?

Comment: Yes it's Ubuntu, the path is of jdk only

Comment: Updating the question

Comment: @TechGeek please check you have the `openjdk-8-jdk` package installed alongside `openjdk-8-jre`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca path updated in question pls check

Comment: So have you checked `openjdk-8-jdk` is installed? Because that still looks like the path for a simple jvm, not a jdk.

Comment: Yes it's installed i can run my Java programs without any issues

Comment: What happens if you run `javac -version` ?

Comment: Note that the fact that the installation directory has "openjdk" in it does not mean that you have a JDK installation.  "OpenJDK" is the name of the open source Java project and (generically) its Java releases.  Not all OpenJDK distros are (full) JDKs.

Comment: @StephenC so what can I do? Now how to know where is jdk installed

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Please answer it.  Also, tell us how you installed Java, and what operating system and distribution you are using.

Comment: I installed directly, m using Ubuntu

Comment: You still did not answer this: "What happens if you run `javac -version` ?"

Answer (score 0):

A JDK is required with Maven, not a JRE. So you have to ensure that JAVA_HOME environment variable points to a JDK to make Maven work.

Answer (score 0):

that openjdk folder was not actual jdk,
i installed jdk online, and pointed eclipse to the installed one
It worked